# how to use wget to download directory with latest timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, curl, wget

i have an internal Linux http server where directories with a specific naming convention will be uploaded on a daily basis from a remote site.

```
url: http://10.10.10.10/test

Contents

test123 
test124
test125
test126
```

All directories will be having date and timestamp as well. Is there any way i can download the latest directory starting with test using wget or curl to my local machine? in this example it is test126

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wget doesn't do that automatically, you can do it in two steps:

1. download http://10.10.10.10/test, parse it, get the last entry
2. feed the result to wget -r

In these cases though the best solution is to set a symlink on the server that points always to the last directory, in your case:

http://10.10.10.10/test/latest -> http://10.10.10.10/test/test126